# Постоянное отображение клавиатуры в ВКонтакте Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

возник такой вопрос, возможно ли сделать постоянное отображение клавиатуры в ВК. Знаю, что можно в настройках выставить отображение кнопки "Начать", но эта функция работает только если диалог пустой. А мне хотелось бы что бы кнопка отображался и у олдов сообщества 
 (то есть, если человек у которого уже начат диалог с сообществом, зайдет в диалог, то у него сразу же будет отображаться кнопка). В оф. документации ВК ничего поэтому поводу не нашел, возможно не досмотрел.

Comment: если не ошибаюсь, там есть параметр one_time, пробовали сделать keyboard = VkKeyboard(one_time=False) ?

Comment: К сожалению, эта функция работает только если кнопка уже есть. А мне нужно чтоб при заходе в диалог, показывалась кнопка для всех. Это как кнопка "Начать", для нового диалога сообщества, только для всех. Не знаю как понятнее объяснить

Comment: если пользователь присоединился к диалогу: показать клавиатуру. только я не помню есть ли там метод который позволяет отловить вступивших в диалог участников

Comment: Тоже думал об этом способе, но пока не нашел такого метода.